# Converting JPQL not having explicit joins to Specifications

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

So, I have this JPL query that fetches a list of users based on filters and search key. Instead of this big query, I want to implement custom Specifications for dynamic filtering.
**My first question** is (though it might be unrelated) how to identify the good practice for filtration queries. It is mentioned that it differs from use-case to use-case, but is there any common hunch that we should opt for a specific solution?
My query has join on two tables, all the blogs or articles I have explored so far contain examples of joins in specifications where entities have explicit relations defined. But in my scenario, there is no explicit relation defined for the foreign key. Upon joining, I am getting the issue that `lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the given name ["fk_id"] on this ManagedType`
**Second question** is how do I create custom specifications for the queries where there's no explicit relation between tables?

Not a very good springboot developer so apologies for bad questions/concepts

Comment: How are you joining exactly? We would need more details on what you are doing and the entities involved - and it is better to keep your question to a specific problem to avoid opinion based questions/answers which, as you said, are situational anyway.

Comment: @Chris yes you are right, actually did not find anything related on the internet. 
So, no explicit relation means there's no joins and foreign key defined. Its just there's a column in a table that has same values with the IDs of another, that's how we fetch any data by applying join where Customer.id = Order.customer_id
And if I have a listing page that contains data from both tables, how can I achieve that using Specifications? Hope its a bit clear now!

Comment: I usually create a relation in the entity to make querying easier, and make it lazy so it isn't required in reads. JPQL is easier though, as you can use "select a from EntityA a join EntityB b on b.id = a.bId where ..". Specifications and criteria API don't allow the join ON without relationships, so you'd have to set it up in the where clause entirely, similar to "select a from EntityA a, EntityB b where b.id = a.bId AND .." using Root<EntityB> entityB = cq.from(EntityB.class);